# neo4j cache, transaction-commits to physical media upon request only?

Tags: neo4j

I've read about neo4j caches in which node/relationship updates can be made.  I also have read about transactional behavior that neo4j database supports.

QUESTION:  is it possible to set up neo4j so that the entire database is in cache, all operations to it are transactional (as needs be), and the in-cache data is only permanently written out to physical media under explicit direction from the API?

Answer (score 2):

**First of all**: Neo4j tries to utilize caches as much as possible.
If you give enough memory for Neo4j caches - they will store all your database in cache.

**Second**: there are several types of [caches](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-caches.html#_configuration_2). Your are looking for `strong` one. It holds objects and never release them. Be sure that you give enough memory for caches (more than database size is).

> This cache will hold on to all data that gets loaded to never release it again. Provides good performance if your graph is small enough to fit in memory.

**Third** - all Neo4j operations **must** be done inside transaction. Using [Cypher transactional endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) you can start/close/rollback transaction, and execute Cypher queries inside them.

They is [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) developed by one of the Neo4j core team representative - [neo4j-tx-participation](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-tx-participation). Info:

> This is a Neo4j Server Extension to make Neo4j REST-API participate in transactions started by the transactional Cypher endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that?

Then you don't need transactions at all, as you loose the durability guarantees.

Not that I know of such a means, there is an in-memory version of Neo4j for testing.

Please note in Neo4j 2.3 the caching will focus on efficient mapping of storage files, not so much second level caches.

Comment: We are doing some non-standard things ...  is the in-memory version of neo4j part of the standard community edition?

Comment: It is part of neo4j testing module. org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:test-jar